# How to have a sticky footer using the Material UI table?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the [Material UI table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) in my project and there is an option to have a "stickyheader" where the header stays fixed to the top of the table. I want to do something similar with the footer where it is fixed to the bottom of the table. I don't see an explicit "stickyfooter" option. Is there a way to do this using CSS or something?